# PHP Copy file to my website from remote site

Tags: php, linux

```
 $link = "http://vcdn8.yobt.tv/content/a8/68/e6/a868e6dc4688ecfc0c26de00ed08db7f871427/vid/1_1024x576.mp4";
copy($link, '../video/video12465123.mp4');
```

I'm trying to copy this video but always stop at between 1 mb - 2 mb , and it says

500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Error log:
[Mon Feb 03 06:36:38 2014] [warn] [client 217.131.165.102] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds
[Mon Feb 03 06:36:38 2014] [error] [client 217.131.165.102] Premature end of script headers: videoekle.php

Comment: Check your PHP logs to get the actual error, and report back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an apache timeout error.  If you run your PHP script from the command line (instead of through apache), you shouldn't get this timeout error.  If you need to run the script through apache, you can increase the FcgidIOTimeout setting in /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf, and restart apache, and that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using curl, forcing timout

```
set_time_limit(400);// to infinity for example
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://vcdn8.yobt.tv/content/a8/68/e6/a868e6dc4688ecfc0c26de00ed08db7f871427/vid/1_1024x576.mp4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Then save it to the file.